# How to hook into the drag event of SortableJS

Tags: javascript, sortablejs, vue.draggable, vuedraggable

I'm trying to hook into the dragover/touchmove event from the *SortableJS* library (1.8.4). The elements are dragging and swapping just fine, but listening to those events do not trigger the callback function I provided them.

The use case is that if the draggable is outside of the `swapThreshold`, but over the target, it should be able to be dropped on the target **without** swapping places with it. Once the draggable reaches the `swapThreshold`, it should then swap places as usual.

```
<draggable
    v-model="itemsArray"
<!-- invert-swap="true"      - this helps, but the elements don't swap until the 
                               draggable is almost off of the target completely -->
<!-- swap-threshold="0.5"    - changing this didn't help -->
<!-- dragover-bubble="true   - seems to have no effect -->
    @dragover="log"       <!-- log() is not being called -->
    @touchmove="log"      <!-- log() is not being called -->
    :move="log"           <!-- log() IS called for :move, and @start, @end, etc. -->
>
  <li v-for="item in itemsArray">{{item}}</li>
</draggable>
```

(the comments are just here for clarity)

I considered a solution in the `move` event but that is only called after a swap takes place, or unreliably as stated in my comment above about the `invert-swap` property

**Note: I'm using *Vue.Draggable* (2.20), but this should also apply if using *SortableJS* directly**

Answer (score 2):

Use @dragover="log" @touchmove="log" in your li - not in draggable component.

Something like this:

```
<li @dragover="log" @touchmove="log" v-for="item in itemsArray">{{item}}</li>
```

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but is there no way to make it work on the parent draggable? Before I switched to a drag & drop library I had the `touchmove` event on the parent and it worked fine. Just wonder if it's being prevented through SortableJS or something..

Comment: draggable is a vue component which after rendering converts to a div. I don't think they expose any event to handle touchmove in parent draggable.